# Simulate the use of a website with a client

Tags: javascript, c#, web, simulation, imacros

I would like to achieve the following scenario:

Create a client that opens a web site, for example www.stackoverflow.com, click a button with an id (for example the button "Ask Question"), fill the forms (knowing the ids of the fields) and press another button.

No, I do not want to do bad things :D I'm only trying to create a demo to customers about a website (I do not have source of this website) and I would like to know if there's a way to program a client in order to reproduce some steps.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can use Selenium for this which is useful for automatic testing of a website

Comment: You can use Selenium for this. There are NUGet packages available for C# in Visual Studio that will allow you to automatically navigate a site in for example IE and Chorme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it for .net, then there is [WatiN](http://watin.org/).

Here is an example how to use it:

```
public void SearchForWatiNOnGoogle()
{
  using (var browser = new IE("http://www.google.com"))
  {
    browser.TextField(Find.ByName("q")).TypeText("WatiN");
    browser.Button(Find.ByName("btnG")).Click();

    bool contains = browser.ContainsText("WatiN");
  }
}
```

p.s. You can also try [Test Recorder](http://watintestrecord.sourceforge.net/) for generating macros.

Answer (score 0):

you can configure a webtest within visual studio

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd293540%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

in the creation of such a webtest you can click trough your website and fill forms. you can use the webtest just once or put it even in a load test to get more information from any website

While running a webtest you get to see a in visual studio browser preform all the steps. you can enter delays between actions like clicking and filling text boxes

a thing to mention is load testing is a visual studio ultimate only function

Comment: "i do not have source of this website" - OP isn't exactly usability testing his own work.

Comment: you dont have to have the source you can make a webtest on a web adress, i fe testet our aplication on the acceptation server, a copy of live to test the amount of users it could handle.

Comment: I do agree. And I'm not questioning the validity of your answer. I'm just pointing out that the OP isn't actually doing this on HIS website. Some people call that spamming or even borderline DOS attack.

Comment: yes a load test is on the border of a dos attack, although it requirs verry much recources to preform a dos attack this way. so it isnt cost effective (; .